# Formula to convert byte array representing signed integer into integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

This question is more generic without a particular language. I am more interested in solving this generally across languages. Every answer I find references a built-in method of something like `getInt32` to extract an integer from a byte array.

I have a byte array which contains the big-endian representation of a signed integer.

```
1 -> [0, 0, 0, 1]
-1 -> [255, 255, 255, 255]
-65535 -> [255, 255, 0, 1]
```

Getting the values for the positive cases are easy:

```
arr[3] | arr[2] << 8 | arr[1] << 16 | arr[0] << 24
```

What I would like to figure out is the more general case. I have been reading about 2s complement, which lead me to the python function from Wikipedia:

```
def twos_complement(input_value, num_bits):
    '''Calculates a two's complement integer from the given input value's bits'''
    mask = 2**(num_bits - 1) - 1
    return -(input_value & mask) + (input_value & ~mask)
```

which in turn lead me to produce this function:

```
# Note that the mask from the wiki function has an additional - 1
mask = 2**(32 - 1)
def arr_to_int(arr):
    uint_val = arr[3] | arr[2] << 8 | arr[1] << 16 | arr[0] << 24
    if (determine_if_negative(uint_val)):
        return -(uint_val & mask) + (uint_val & ~mask)
    else:
        return uint_val
```

In order for my function to work I need to fill in `determine_if_negative` (I should mask the signed bit and check if it is 1). But is there a standard formula to handle this? One thing I found is that in some languages, like Go, the bitshift might overflow the int value.

This is pretty hard to search because I get a thousand results explaining the difference between big-endian and little-endian or results explaining twos complement, and many more giving examples of using the standard library but I haven't seen a complete formula for bitwise functions.

Is there a canonical example in C or similar language of converting a char array using only array access and bitwise functions (ie, no memcpy or pointer casting or tricky stuff)

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise method only works properly for unsigned values so you will need to build the unsigned integer and then convert to signed. The code could be:

```
int32_t val( uint8_t *s )
{
    uint32_t x = ((uint32_t)s[0] << 24) + ((uint32_t)s[1] << 16) + ((uint32_t)s[2] << 8) + s[3];
    return x;
}
```

Note, this assumes you are on a 2's complement system which also defines unsigned->signed conversion as no change in repesentation.   If you want to support other systems too , it would be more complicated.

The casts are necessary so that the shift is performed over the right width.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala personally I press Submit at the wrong time apparently

Answer (score 0):

Even c might be too high level for this. After all, the exact representation of int is machine dependent. On top of that, not all integer types on all systems are 2s complement.

When you mention a byte array and converting it to integer you must specify what format that byte array implies.

If you assume 2s complement and little endian (like intel/amd). Then the last byte contains the sign.

For simplicity's sake lets start with a 4 digit 2s complement integer,then byte byte, then 2 byte integers and then 4.

```
BIN SIGNED_DEC   UNSIGNED_DEC
000   0             0            
001   1             1
010   2             2
100   -4(oops)      4
101   -3            5
110   -1            6
111   -1            7
---
123
```

let each bit be b3,b2,b1, where b1 is the most significant bit(and sign)
then the formula would be:

```
b3*2^2+b2*2^1-b1*4
```

for a byte we have 4 bits and the formula would look like this:

```
b4*2^3 + b3*2^2+b2*2^1-b1*2^3
```

for 2 bytes it is the same but we have to multiple the most significant byte by 256 and the negative value would be 256^2 or 2^16.

```
  /**
   * returns calculated value of 2s complement bit string.
   * expects string of bits 0or1. if a chanracter is not 1 it is considered 0.
   * 
   */
  public static long twosComplementFromBitArray(String input) {
    if(input.length()<2) throw new RuntimeException("intput too short ");
    int sign=input.charAt(0)=='1'?1:0;
    long unsignedComplementSum=1;
    long unsignedSum=0;

    for(int i=1;i<input.length();++i) {
      char c=input.charAt(i);
      int val=(c=='1')?1:0;
      unsignedSum=unsignedSum*2+val;
      unsignedComplementSum*=2;
    }
    return unsignedSum-sign*unsignedComplementSum;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(twosComplementFromBitArray("000"));
    System.out.println(twosComplementFromBitArray("001"));
    System.out.println(twosComplementFromBitArray("010"));
    System.out.println(twosComplementFromBitArray("011"));
    System.out.println(twosComplementFromBitArray("100"));
    System.out.println(twosComplementFromBitArray("101"));
    System.out.println(twosComplementFromBitArray("110"));
    System.out.println(twosComplementFromBitArray("111"));
  }
```

outputs:

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
-4
-3
-2
-1
```